# Spring non transactional call from sessionTransacted=true DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I have a DefaultMessageListenerContainer configured for IBM MQ. sessionTransacted property is set to true. from within the listener I use JMSTemplate to call another MQ service but due to sessionTransacted being set to true the JMSTemplate call does not go through untill the end and so I do not get the response. If there a way I could this one make this one JMSTemplate MQ call not participate in the transaction and get reply when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wire a different connection factory instance into the template, the template operation(s) will not run in the container's transaction.